# Convert string to date using sql and vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the query below in access and wanted to use it in VBA...

```
SQL = "UPDATE Sales SET Sales.order_date = CDate(Right([data],2)+" / "+Mid([data],5,2)+" / "+Left([data],4));"
```

I keep getting error due to the way I am building the string to then execute.

I have tried to put the

```
& "/" &
```

to build the string but get an error when executing the SQL...

How should I build the string?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use DateSerial for this if data is a field of your table:

```
SQL = "UPDATE Sales SET Sales.order_date = DateSerial(Left([data],4), Mid([data],5,2), Right([data],2))"
```

Answer (score 0):

just escaped the / as '/' and worked...

```
SQL = "UPDATE Sales SET Sales.order_date = CDate(Right([data],2)+ '/' + Mid([data],5,2) + '/' + Left([data],4));"
```